# On firebase auth, are there cloud triggers for when a user logs in?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

We would like to send an email, sms, or push notification every time a user logs in.

Is there a way to do this with firebase auth?

A trigger to a firebase-cloud-function would be ideal, but it does not seem like there is one.

Thanks!

Comment: Not presently, but I've seen the feature requested before.

Comment: Your app itself current has the best sense of when a user actually logs in using the UI you provide.  When you detect a login from the client side, you can do something like trigger an HTTPS or database trigger to respond to that event.

Comment: Looking for the same, just a simple lastSeen field update on my external DB requires this trigger. Any updates on it?